# Javascript Go button

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I would like to create a GO button for my current code, but I don't know how.

```
    jQuery(function($) {

var data = [ // The data
    ['Select Province', [
        'Select City'
    ]],
    ['Alberta', [
        'Select City', 'Airdrie', 'Calgary', 'Cold Lake', 'Edmonton', 'Fort Saskatchewan', 'Grande Prairie', 'Leduc', 'Lethbridge', 'Medicine Hat', 'Red Deer'
    ]],
    ['British Columbia', [
        'Select City', 'Abbotsford', 'Burnaby', 'Chilliwack', 'Coquitlam', 'Kamloops', 'Langley', 'Nanaimo', 'New Westminister', 'North Vancouver', 'Port Coquitlam', 'Port Moody', 'Prince George', 'Richmond', 'Surrey', 'Vancouver', 'Vernon', 'Victoria'
    ]],
    ['Manitoba', [
        'Select City', 'Brandon', 'Dauphin', 'Flin Flon', 'Morden', 'Portage la Prairie', 'Selkirk', 'Steinbach', 'Thompson', 'Winkler', 'Winnipeg'
    ]],
    ['New Brunswick', [
        'Select City', 'Bathurst', 'Campbellton', 'Dieppe', 'Edmundston', 'Fredericton', 'Miramichi', 'Moncton', 'Saint John'
    ]],
    ['Newfoundland and Labrador', [
        'Select City', 'Corner Brook', 'Mount Pearl', 'St. Johns'
    ]],
    ['Northwest Territories', [
        'Select City', 'Fort Simpson', 'Inuvik', 'Sachs Harbour', 'Yellowknife'
    ]],
    ['Nova Scotia', [
        'Select City', 'Amherst', 'Cape Breton', 'Glace Bay', 'Halifax', 'Kentville', 'New Glasgow', 'Sydney Mines', 'Truno'
    ]],
    ['Nunavut', [
        'Select City', 'Alert', 'Eureka', 'Iqaluit'
    ]],
    ['Ontario', [
        'Select City', 'Barrie', 'Belleville', 'Brampton', 'Brant', 'Brantford', 'Brockville', 'Burlington', 'Cambridge', 'Cornwall', 'Elliot Lake', 'Guelph', 'Haldimand County', 'Hamilton', 'Kawartha Lakes', 'Kenora', 'Kingston', 'Kitchener', 'London', 'Markham', 'Mississauga', 'Niagara Falls', 'Norfolk County', 'North Bay', 'Orillia', 'Oshawa', 'Ottawa', 'Owen Sound', 'Peterborough', 'Pickering', 'Quinte West', 'Sarnia', 'Sault Ste. Marie', 'St. Catherines', 'St.Thomas', 'Stratford', 'Sudbury', 'Thunder Bay', 'Timmons', 'Toronto', 'Vaughan', 'Waterloo', 'Welland', 'Windsor', 'Woodstock'
    ]],
    ['Prince Edward Island', [
        'Select City', 'Charlottetown', 'Summerside'
    ]],
    ['Quebec', [
        'Select City', 'Alma', 'Baie-Comeau', 'Beaconsfield', 'Beloeil', 'Blainville', 'Boisbriand', 'Gatineau', 'Laval', 'Longueuil', 'Lévis', 'Montreal', 'Quebec City', 'Repentigny', 'Saguenay', 'Saint-Jean-sur-Richelieu', 'Sherbrooke', 'Terrebonne', 'Trois-Rivières'
    ]],
    ['Saskatchewan', [
        'Select City', 'Estevan', 'Lloydminster', 'Moose Jaw', 'Prince Albert', 'Regina', 'Saskatoon', 'Swift Current', 'Yorkton'
    ]],
    ['Yukon', [
        'Select City', 'Carmacks', 'Dawson City', 'Faro', 'Haines Junction', 'Mayo', 'Teslin', 'Watson Lake', 'Whitehorse'
    ]]
];

$a = $('#a'); // The dropdowns
$b = $('#b');

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var first = data[i][0];
    $a.append($("<option>"). // Add options
       attr("value",first).
       data("sel", i).
       text(first));
}

$a.change(function() {
    var index = $(this).children('option:selected').data('sel');
    var second = data[index][1]; // The second-choice data

    $b.html(''); // Clear existing options in second dropdown

    for(var j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
        $b.append($("<option>"). // Add options
           attr("value",second[j]).
           data("sel", j).
           text(second[j]));
    }
}).change(); // Trigger once to add options at load of first choice
    });
```

It consists of 2 drop downs, first choice is a province which then in the second drop down shows the cities for that province. I would like the user to choose a city then click a GO button when they've made their choice, which would then go to a link of my choosing.

Please if someone could help, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: A 'go' button? What exactly does this button have to do? Just go to a URL with the chosen selected options?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward.  Make a button with a click event, then in the event, get the dropdown values and go to the URL.  Which part of that are you stuck on?

Comment: Yes, the GO button needs to go to a URL. Once they choose the city from the second drop down then they would click GO, it would take them to whatever URL that goes with that city. Basically I'm stuck on how to move forward with this. I get creating a button but I'm an extreme noob when it comes to JS how would I create the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit complex, but essentially it's this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WNkUA/1/

Code below as well.

HTML:

```
<select id="one"></select>
<select id="two"><option><- Select a Province</option></select><br />
<button id="button">GO</button><br />
<div id="log"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
   $("#one").append(
       $("<option>")
       .attr("value",i)
       .text(data[i][0])
   );
}
$("#one").on("change",function(){
   var val = $("#one").val();
    var prov = data[val][1];
    $("#two").empty();
    for (i=0;i<prov.length;i++){
       $("#two").append(
        $("<option>").attr("value",prov[i]).text(prov[i])
       );
    }
});
$("#two").on("change",function(){
   var val = $("#two").val();
    $("#button").off("click").on("click",function(){
       //window.location = val; //Customize url here. 
        //Temporary to demonstrate:
        $("#log").text(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: That is really awesome, thanks for taking the time. But where do I put the urls? In the part where you have commented? Can you just give an example of what one would look like?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the page the Go button will take the user to when they click it if they've selected, for example, Quebec City?

Comment: I suppose just use www.google.ca for now, I'm still creating the categories for the cities.

Comment: Then you would replace that comment with this: `window.location = 'www.google.ca';`  So when they click the button, that's where it will take them.  If you want to automatically do a google search for whatever city they've selected, you could do something like `window.location = 'www.google.ca/search?q='+val.replace(" ","+");`